# Build an array out of a SQL query

Tags: php, sql, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I'm programming a script for a WordPress plugin which should extend the plugin. Right now I'm optimizing my script. But my problem is to handle the data... The data get applied by the plugin. So I cannot change anything on that. I must deal with it.

Here you can see a snippet of the database. But it is only fortune that I selected to different posts  where the amount of `product_shop_0/1/2/3` is same... It is variable!
[image]

At the end I would love to have an array like this:

```
array(92) {
  [0]=> int(5) "24202"
  array(4) {
    ["product_shops_0"]=>
    array(4) {
       ["product_shops_0_price"]=> double(4) "35.99"
       ["product_shops_0_price_old"]=> double(0) ""
       ["product_shops_0_shop"]=> int(5) "18319"
       ["product_shops_0_link"]=> string(78) "http://www.kinguin...."
    }
    ["product_shops_1"]=>
    array(4) {
       ...
    }
    ["product_shops_2"]=>
    array(4) {
       ...
    }
    ["product_shops_3"]=>
    array(4) {
       ["product_shops_3_price"]=> double(4) "40.39"
       ["product_shops_3_price_old"]=> double(0) ""
       ["product_shops_3_shop"]=> int(5) "18315"
       ["product_shops_3_link"]=> string(78) "http://www.gameladen...."
    }
  }
```

My problem at the moment is I do not know how to solve this problem. product_shops_0_price`. **EVERY**`post_id`has it's own`product_shops_0_price`. So, it's starts again at 0. Those data belongs together:

- Alls `meta_keys` and `meta_values` who have the same `post_id``
- Those data should get split up on `product_shops_0`, `product_shops_1` and so on...

Does anyone know how I can stack that array like this?
I tried it already, but I cannot solve it...

Here my try:

```
$stmt = $database->query("SELECT `meta_key`, `meta_value` FROM `fWR6qIN_postmeta` WHERE (meta_key like '$price_meta' OR meta_key like '$price_old_meta' OR meta_key like '$link_meta' OR meta_key like '$shop_meta')");

$map = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){

    $price = null;
    $price_old = null;
    $link = "";
    $shop = "";

    if($row["meta_key"] == $price_meta){
        $price = $row["meta_value"];
    }elseif($row["meta_key"] == $price_old_meta){
        $price_old = $row["meta_value"];
    }elseif($row["meta_key"] == $link_meta){
        $link = $row["meta_value"];
    }elseif($row["meta_key"] == $shop_meta) {
        $shop = $row["meta_value"];
    }else{
        echo "Error\n";
    }

    $tmp = array(
        $price_meta =>  $price,
        $price_old_meta => $price_old,
        $link_meta => $link,
        $shop_meta => $shop

    );

    array_push($map, $tmp);
}
```

Would be very happy about help!
Thank You and Greetings!

Comment: are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`?

Comment: is count is finite or infinite ? i.e. `product_shops_0` .. `product_shops_2` ... `product_shops_n` **n** is know or unknown?

Comment: I'm using `MySQL` the count is variable and unknown for each `post_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, May it could help you: For regex test [click here](https://3v4l.org/hIYmZ)

```
<?php
$stmt = $database->query("SELECT pm.post_id, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value FROM fWR6qIN_postmeta pm GROUP BY pm.post_id, pm.meta_key");

$map = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())
{
    preg_match('/^(product_shops_\d*)_(\S*)/', $row['meta_key'], $matches);
    $product_offset = $matches[1];

    $map[$row['post_id']][$product_offset][$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
}
```

Comment: I get `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable` for `preg_match_all('/([\d]+)/', $meta['meta_key'], $matches);` and `$meta_array[$meta['post_id']][$parent_key][$meta['meta_key']] = $meta['meta_value'];`

Comment: @FrazeJr. I have updated the answer. I used different variable `$meta` instead of `$row`. Please check it and let me know

Comment: @FrazeJr. still you getting error or not...tell me??

Comment: Now I just get `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 on line 28`. This is this line `$product_offset = $matches[0][1];`. But where do you store the values?

Comment: @FrazeJr. please check the variable `$meta_array` which i replace with `$map`.

Comment: Yeah, I see it. But they are not stored in a extra Array.... all product_shops get stored in one array... how can I split them up in subarray of the post Id array?

Comment: Please check `$product_offset = $matches[1];` this. Also you can test result over [https://3v4l.org/hIYmZ](https://3v4l.org/hIYmZ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140060/discussion-between-gaurav-and-fraze-jr).